# Get Msrp product price from Quote

Tags: checkout, magento-1, product-attribute, quote

I'm trying to get **MSRP Product Prices** in `cart/checkout` pages.
The price returned by the following code is always zero.

```
foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getId()); 
    $_msrpPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($product->getMsrp(),true,true);
    var_dump($_msrpPrice);

}
```

Any alternatives?

Comment: Your Magento version is 1. You did not specify this.

Comment: I added it as a tag

Comment: Can you verify that the msrp for these items is not 0?  is there any value returned for `$product->getMsrp()`?  If not, do a check on the line that you populate the product to make sure it is being loaded, i.e. you are getting the correct value from `$item->getId()`.

Comment: @mtr.web I'm testing this with two products added to cart, one of them has mtrl price and one of them not. But both products return $_msrpPrice = 0,00.

Comment: @mtr.web also $item->getId() returns the product id normally

Comment: @mtr.web you gave me a hint. $item->getId() returns a value, but it's not the products id. To get the real product id I had to use $item->getProductId(). Please post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through debugging, it turns out that `$item->getId()` does not return the products' id.  Instead, `$item->getProductId()` will work, and here is the edited code:

```
foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId()); 
    $_msrpPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($product->getMsrp(),true,true);
    var_dump($_msrpPrice);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of loading each product you can define custom attributes in a moduels `config.xml`. Just add this to global section:

```
    <sales>
        <quote>
            <item>
                <product_attributes>
                    <msrp />
                </product_attributes>
            </item>
        </quote>
    </sales>
```

Now this should work too ...

```
foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
    $_msrpPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($item->getProduct()->getMsrp(), true, true);
    var_dump($_msrpPrice);
}
```